# How to evaluate the best K for LDA using Mallet?

Tags: cluster-analysis, lda, topic-modeling, mallet

I am using Mallet api to extract topic from twitter data and I have already
extracted topics which are seems good topic. But I am facing problem
to estimating K.

For example I fixed K value from 10 to 100.
So, I have taken different number of topics from the data.
But, now I would like to estimate which K is best.
There are some algorithm I know as

1. Perplexity
2. Empirical likelihood
3. Marginal likelihood (Harmonic mean method)
4. Silhouette

I found a method model.estimate() which may be used to estimate with different value of K.
But I am not getting any idea to show the value of K is best for the model.
Does anyone give some idea about it with some sample code? Thanks.

Comment: consider gensim Hdpmodel (Hierarchical Dirichlet Processes).